# Most efficient method of storing URLs for later viewing? — e.g. Bookmark addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, bookmarks, browser-tabs, session

I have 200 tabs open in Firefox (3 windows), 100 tabs open in Opera (1 window), 37 tabs open in Chrome (1 window) and 51 tabs open in Firefox Nightly (x64, v9; 2 windows).

Obviously my efficiency has gone to hell with all this clutter.

**Could you recommend an addon for Firefox which is more efficient than having all these windows, tabs and browsers open constantly?**

I am thinking maybe Speed-Dial groups, or some other group bookmark orientated "Keep for later" addon... or maybe a Bookmark addon providing keyboard-shortcuts for "bookmark to specific group" functionality.

Offline storage (i.e. for viewing on the train or on the slow-connection at home) would also be good.

Comment: This is what Bookmarks are for.

Comment: Please do not add signatures to your questions on Super User, as per the FAQ: http://superuser.com/faq#signatures - I have already edited it out twice.

Comment: On OS X, you could just drag them into the Dock (document area at the right of the separator) for later viewing.

Comment: Not using OSX, also that would == clutter.

Comment: surfasb: I suppose... but the current bookmark functionality is too limited. Know of an addon to bind keyboard shortcuts with "bookmark to group <x>"?

Comment: "Obviously my efficiency has gone to hell with all this clutter." Maybe you have found the root of the problem, solving this issue would just lead to more clutter. Any good reason to have so many tabs open at one time?

Comment: Well, it used to make my research more efficient. But now it's just overload, which is why I'm searching for a good bookmarking addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up switching to bookmarks, but it has given me the problem I thought it would. I never open the bookmarks menu...

All well...

Answer (score 0):

I stumble over "Read It Later"-Addon for Firefox. I didn't test it yet, so it is only a hint: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/read-it-later/

Comment: Thanks, seems to be featured as well. I've just finished testing it, it's not what I'm looking for, as it doesn't have groups. :/